# NSString to NSDate dont work on iDevice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

i have a problem to convert a NSString to a NSDate and back to a formatted NSString. The codesnippet works without any problem on the iOS Simulator but doesnt work on my iPhone 4.

```
NSString *pubDate = @"Tue, 18 Oct 2011 05:00:00 +0100";

NSDateFormatter *formater1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater1 setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];

NSDate *d = [formater1 dateFromString:pubDate];
NSLog(@"d: %@", d);


NSDateFormatter *formater2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater2 setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];

NSString *k = [formater2 stringFromDate:d]; 
NSLog(@"k: %@", k);

[formater1 release];
[formater2 release];
```

The output from the simulator is:

```
d: 2011-10-18 04:00:00 +0000
k: 18 Oct 2011
```

The output on the device is:

```
d: (null)
k: (null)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a locale on the date formatters.

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];

//...
formater1.locale = locale;

//...
formater2.locale = locale;

//...
[locale release];
```

If you don't set the locale then user's settings can change the provided string to conform with user's setting, such as change 12h to 24h clock or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the device is not set to english, thus it can't parse the `Tue` and `Oct` in the `pubDat`.

Try adding a an locale to the `NSDateFormatter`:

```
[formater1 setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"] autorelease]];
```